# What does mean of "You have not been profiled yet"? How to list user into any profile?

Tags: habitat

How we can assign one profile/pattern to logged-in/non loggedin user of sitecore

As I understood , if we set the Profile card on any Sitecore page and then use personalization by pattern card and visit same targeted page again and again 
then Sitecore assigned user into one pattern based on the page visit.

I have created profile/and pattren card as below and set the personalization  and visiting on  personalizatied pages again and again but still its showing
**"You have not been profiled yet"**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your Sitecore license supports xdb? Moreover, loads the showconfig.aspx page and see if the `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` is set to `true`.

Comment: Both values are already set to true.